# Potentially scam email about password change

Tags: email, passwords, gmail

I received an email from Google regarding a password change in an account of mine (which I did not) and I find it extremely difficult to identify the source of it.

It seems legit in every way, BUT there is a strong indication it is a scam.

The message refers to a real email of mine as a Google account, yet it is a yahoo account. It specifically states:

"The password for your Google Account a-real-address-of-mine@yahoo.com was recently changed."
...

The fact is that this yahoo account is indeed linked as recovery account to my gmail account, so that makes me suspicious.

I did try to logout and login again using my password, both on yahoo and on google and all was ok, so I can only assume that the password was not actually changed and this is a scam mail. So I started investigating for details on this suspicious email (the links, the details of the sender etc). They all seem ok, but it doesnt make sence.

Can anybody please give me a reasonable scenario, how could this happen (could this be a mistake og Google)?
Also, could you please give me advice on what to search on the email raw content to spot the scam?

thanx